# CMOS Logic Gate Interpretation

Tags: logic-gates, cmos

So I came across this interesting question while researching CMOS logic gates:

[image]

As is says, a logic function \$Y\$ is given and you are required to create a logic network that implements it. I am familiar with how to draw CMOS logic gates when given logic functions, but I am unsure how to interpret \$Y\$. From my understanding, say I wanted to draw the PUN first, I would need to solve for \$Y\$ in terms of complemented variables. Likewise, if I wanted to draw the PDN first,  I would need \$\overline{Y}\$ in terms of uncomplemented variables (where the bar indicates a complement).

How would you interpret \$Y\$?

Can you assume that \$Y=\overline{ABC+D}\$? If this assumption is valid, then going through the logic gives \$Y=(\overline{A}+\overline{B}+\overline{C})\overline{D}\$, which I can draw a PUN for since \$Y\$ is now in terms of only complemented variables. The PDN could then be found via duality.

Another thought I had was to represent uncomplemented variables as double complemented variables (i.e. \$A=\overline{\overline{A}}\$ and so on) and solve from there.

Comment: Since this looks like homework I will only give you hints. No, I don't think you can show, using Boolean algebra, that \$Y = \overline{ABC + D}\$. A "compliment" is something nice that someone says about you. The word you want to use is "complement". Beyond that, I don't think you have the correct procedure in mind. To find the PDN you want \$\overline{Y}\$ in terms of uncomplemented variables, because a high input to an NMOS transistor causes a low output.

Comment: Working it in my head, if you only have non-inverted inputs available I think you'll need one inverter... and one way would be to calculate !Y, and then follow it with an inverter to get Y. De Morgan's theorem is your friend here.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! The more I work on the problem, the more I realize that inverters will be needed, since \$Y\$ can't be solved in terms of only complimented variables and \$\overline{Y}\$ can't be solved in terms of only uncomplimented variables. \$Y\$ and \$\overline{Y}\$ would have to be solved separately, since I now believe that duality cannot be applied. The PDN and PUN circuits would look fairly simple then, with inputs into the PMOSs and NMOSs being \$\overline{A}\$, \$\overline{B}\$, \$\overline{C}\$ and \$\overline{D}\$ as opposed to \$A\$, \$B\$, \$C\$ and \$D\$.

Answer (score 0):

The initial assumption is inverted.

The use of all NOR functions in open drain inverters means shared pulling R’s might produce a simpler answer.

\$Y=ABC+D\$ as given

\$Y={(\overline{A}+\overline{B}+\overline{C})}+ \overline{\overline{D}}\$

Simple diodes shared are “wired OR” and shared open drains are “wired NORs”

Then you may choose the N or P types with complementary output bias for either state active low impedance 0 or 1 in this selection of PUN and PDN’s.  Normally Nch with PUN’s were preferred for the output as Nch were slightly lower output impedance for the same chip size.

Comment: Thank you for your response Tony. How exactly did you get the expression \$Y=(\overline{A}+\overline{B}+\overline{C})+\overline{\overline{D}}\$ ? If you double complement each variable, wouldn't you end up with \$Y=(\overline{\overline{A}}+\overline{\overline{B}}+\overline{\overline{C}})+\overline{\overline{D}}\$ ?